# deis Register without external IP

Tags: docker, kubernetes, paas, iaas, deis

[Deis](https://deis.com/docs/workflow/quickstart/deploy-an-app/) register need a external IP, but I install k8s by [docker-multinode](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/), I can't get the external IP for my IaaS, how to use deis in this solution ?

```
$ kubectl --namespace=deis get svc deis-router
NAME          CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                            AGE
deis-router   10.0.0.97    <pending>     80/TCP,443/TCP,2222/TCP,9090/TCP   8h
```